# Facebook ads only shown in apps downloaded from play store

Tags: android, google-play, ads, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-audience-network

I have published my app in Google Play store by adding Facebook ads. When I download the app from Google Play store, the ads are seen in all devices. But when I use ShareIt to send it to another device or install the signed apk directly, the ads are not being filled.

Is there anything I can do so that Facebook ads will be shown regardless of the source of app?

Comment: No that the not an issue. Please confirm that whether the facebook native app is installed on other phone in which you have installed the app using shareit.

Comment: I tested on the same device in which Facebook app is already installed.

Comment: Have you logged(Facebook Application) in with your main admin facebook account in which your app is registered with the developers.facebook.com

Comment: When the admin account is logged in, ads are shown in both cases. But when a different account is logged in, ads are shown only for the case in which app is installed from the play store.

Comment: Please check whether your app is live and approved by the facebook on developers.facebook.com?

Comment: It is live and approved. If you think it hasn't been approved, how are ads shown in the app downloaded from play store?

Comment: But it will only show you in your admin account that's why i should have to confirm once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the Facebook Audience Network Policy (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/policy#other)

> Audience Network is only available to apps offered in Apple iTunes or Google Play, unless you have our prior written approval.